# Dynamic query VBA How add value to column from one query to second

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in excel Sheet("CustomReport"):

```
 SalesOrder  Value1      Value2      Value3     Links
 1           Jonas       Station1    8          https://x.com=1
 2           Greg        Station1    5          https://x.com=2
 3           Anton       Station1    1          https://x.com=3
 ...         ...         ...         ...        ...
```

Number of rows in this query is always different when it is refreshed

And based on this webquery I generate dynamic webquery in macro. For example: DynamicQuery1 save data from report https://x.com=1 to Sheet name "Orders" started from A1 and ending A{X} value (reports have diffrents number of rows).

DynamicQuery2 save data from report https://x.com=2 to the same Sheet "Orders" but started from A{X+1}.

This is the macro:

```
Sub Test()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Orders").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Orders"
    Dim c As Range, DataSpot As Range
    Set c = Sheets("CustomReport").Range("E2")
    While c.Value <> ""

    Dim URL As String
    URL = c.Value
        Set DataSpot = Cells(Sheets("Orders").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row + 1, 1)


                    Sheets("Orders").Select
                    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & URL, Destination:=Range(DataSpot.Address))
                        .Name = "team2289_2"
                        .FieldNames = True
                        .RowNumbers = False
                        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                        .PreserveFormatting = False
                        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                        .BackgroundQuery = True
                        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
                        .SavePassword = False
                        .SaveData = True
                        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                        .RefreshPeriod = 0
                        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
                        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingAll
                        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
                        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
                        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
                        .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
                        .WebDisableRedirections = False
                        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                    End With
        Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Wend


End Sub
```

And now i need add new formula to this macro.
This is structure reports from "Links"

Example Sheets from sheet "Orders"

```
WorkOrder  ID          Item2       Column4    Level3    <----- Report Sales Order 1 
Number4    TOPLEVEL    Jonas       Station1   5
212121212  2           Station1    5          2
31212121   3           Station1    1          4
...         ...         ...         ...        ...

TextSome   TOPLEVEL    Jonas       Station1   5         <----- Report Sales Order 2
212121212  2           Station1    5          2
31212121   3           Station1    1          4
...         ...         ...         ...        ...

...        ...          ...         ...        ...<----- Report Sales Order 3

DADADA   TOPLEVEL    Jonas       Station1   5         <----- Report Sales Order 4
212121212  2           Station1    5          2
31212121   3           Station1    1          4
...         ...         ...         ...        ...
```

I need add formula, when every loop make, makro add to new column value from workorder, where ID="TOPLEVEL", but if report dont exist then put blank value.

```
   SalesOrder    Value1    Value2      Value3     Links             WOTOP
   1             Jonas     Station1    8          https://x.com=1   Number4
   2             Greg      Station1    5          https://x.com=2   TextSome
   3             Anton     Station1    1          https://x.com=3   blank
   4             Anton     Station1    1          https://x.com=3   DADA
   ...           ...         ...         ...        ...
```

`